# How can I mount a painting paper onto wood?

Tags: painting, adhesives, paper

I have an oil painting - done on oil painting paper - which I would like to mount onto wood (plywood or solid).

**How can I achieve an archival bound of paper to wood?**

I'm especially interested in the kind of adhesive to use - does it depend on the paint medium (i.e. do I have to use a different adhesive for acrylic) and do I need to prepare the wood in a special way?

Comment: Is "onto" as in surface mounting an absolute requirement, as opposed to trapping between wood and glass, or mounting in a backed frame that clamps the edges?

Comment: @ChrisH yes "onto" is a requirement (partly due to the painting covering the entire paper).

Comment: Has anyone thought of doing a spray adhesive like a glue spray, like Elmer's glue spray adhesive. Also wondering rubber cement, which is commonly used in art application. To the back of the paper. The tricky part would be putting the paper down in a way that it doesn't wrinkle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PVA glue which is specifically used for book-binding would be safe for the artwork as well as safe for the wood that it is mounted to. Making sure the wood is sealed appropriately before applying the artwork would be an interest before using the PVA glue.

Pros:
PH neutral acid free
Will not become brittle over time
Says it's reversible

How To Mount Artwork To Wood: https://www.strathmoreartist.com/blog-reader/how-to-mount-artwork-to-a-piece-of-wood.html

Product Source: [https://www.amazon.com/Books-Hand-Neutral-Adhesive-BBHM217/dp/B0025TZ26Q/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0025TZ26Q)

Comment: I would like to damage the painting as little as possible (also over time) this does not seem like the right option for me.

Comment: Hello Vincent! thank you for your reply. I will ponder your input and update my answer.

Comment: Question updated to concern of damaging painting

Answer (score 2):

Wheat paste or rabbit skin glue. They will not release chemicals into the paper that will degrade it over time.

Unfortunately oil paints on paper is *very* non-archival if the paper was not sized or sealed with gesso or something equivalent prior to painting. The oils will eat away the paper as fast as anything you glue the paper to the board with.

Comment: the painting is on "oil-painting paper" I hope its a bit archival.

Comment: rebusB, I am also wondering long term what is in the wood, if it was treated for longevity. How that will affect the oil painting in the future.